# Activity started with request code does not launch with singleTop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to apply single top to an activity that starts with a request code. I have tried both applying `launchMode=singleTop` to the activity in the Android Manifest, as well as setting the Intent flag for singleTop. However, if I launch the activity with a request code other than the default (-1), it will never call `onNewIntent` and will instantiate several activities on top of each other on the stack. Once I remove the request code and have it default to `-1`, however, it respects the launchMode I define.

I carefully read over the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode), but was unable to find anything there or elsewhere online that might explain why android seems to ignore launch mode when an activity is started with a request code. Is there a work around for this? Why does it do this in the first place?